# // vs /// vs # for commenting in dart, what's the difference?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project I have seen different ways to comment: //(I use this way) , /// and #(like python) .Can you please explain me what's the difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you want can be found on the official dart documentation

here is the link: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#comments